# Disk un mounting after write operations on samba

Tags: mount, samba, raspberrypi, smb, samba4

I have samba file sharing enabled on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS on orange pi Lite 2. Drive attached to the USB 3.0 port is Samsung SSD 840 pro.  Read operations are working fine but when I try to write on it then after few MBs it unmounts and remounts on the different mount point goes from usb0 to usb1, if it fails again then usb2 and so on. Small files get written properly but big files after 100-240 MB fail.

**details**:

> **Disk**: /dev/sda1 
>   **Auto mount point**: /media/usb0 
>   **smdb version**: Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
>   **Drive file System**: FAT32 (happens on ext4 and exFAT too)

**EDIT**: logs when it crashed

**File Name**:  log.macbookpro-7666

[2019/05/23 23:26:10.408147,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:406(sys_get_quota)
  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]! 
[2019/05/23 23:26:10.409523,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:406(sys_get_quota)
  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!

**Verbose Log**

[2019/05/23 23:40:10.553130,  3] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:433(sys_get_quota)
  sys_get_vfs_quota() failed for mntpath[/media/sdb1] bdev[/dev/sdb1] qtype[2] id[1001]: Function not implemented 
[2019/05/23 23:40:10.554336,  3] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:433(sys_get_quota)
  sys_get_vfs_quota() failed for mntpath[/media/sdb1] bdev[/dev/sdb1] qtype[4] id[1001]: Function not implemented 
 
[2019/05/23 23:40:10.688455,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:1050(close_cnum)
  macbookpro-7666 (ipv4:192.168.0.134:49933) closed connection to service Samsung SMB 
[2019/05/23 23:40:10.732347,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:252(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (NT_STATUS_END_OF_FILE)

Comment: If you're using the same drive regularly, why not give it a static mount (using UUID in /etc/fstab [fstab = file system table])?  Is there a reason you don't?

Comment: I tried just that, I am having the same problem. Now it is crashing but mounting to the same mount point. See the post I added logs from crash.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, After several hours I've found a solution. Here are the 3 lines you have to add in samba configuration.

> use sendfile = no 
>  
>   large readwrite = no 
>   max xmit = 16644

Source: [gentoo forum](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-215361-start-0.html)

Comment: Interesting. The only mechanism I know of that automatically mounts usb drives to /media/usb[0-7] is a utility called usbmount which is known to interfere with the normal usb udisks automounting functionality of the desktop. I thought it was removed the repository but it appears it's still there. Is there a reason you are using it?